# Coldfusion 9 cfscript cfcookie and cookie (script style)

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, httponly, cookie-httponly

I am trying to set my cookie CFIDE and CFTOKEN to be HTTPOnly in Coldfusion 9...

Here is what I have tried (didn't error but didn't work):

```
cookie.CFID = "#session.cfid#,httpOnly='true'";
cookie.CFTOKEN = "#session.cftoken#,httpOnly='true'";
```

I also tried (no go...and no error):

```
cookie.CFID = "#session.cfid#;httpOnly='true'";
cookie.CFTOKEN = "#session.cftoken#;httpOnly='true'";
```

And this (which I think only works in CF10):

```
cookie.CFID = {value="#session.cfid#", httpOnly="true"};
cookie.CFTOKEN = {value="#session.cftoken#", httpOnly="true"};
```

Then this (didn't error but didn't work):

```
cookie( name="CFID" value="#session.cfid#" httpOnly="true" );
cookie( name="CFTOKEN" value="#session.cftoken#" httpOnly="true" );
```

When I run these I do a empty cache hard reload in Chrome. When the page reloads I should see the Resources Cookies HTTPOnly column show check boxes.

I'm probably exhausted and could have hit the right combo of things above and I got a false positive on failure from jumping around too much. Sometimes cached things get the best of me.

I have the CFML container style that works but my `Application.cfc` is all script style and I want to keep it that way...So how do I do this script style in Coldfusion 9?

**Update for my fix:**

I used the `getPageContex()` below, but it didn't work as it was.  Also `onSessionStart()` event handler changed to create the `session.CFID` and `session.CFTOKEN` with the `CreateUUID()` which is also new in my `Application.cfc` file.  So for posterity here is what that block of code looks like.

```
function onSessionStart(){
getPageContext().getResponse().addHeader("Set-Cookie", "CFID=#session.CFID#;path=/;HTTPOnly");
getPageContext().getResponse().addHeader("Set-Cookie", "CFTOKEN=#session.CFTOKEN#;path=/;HTTPOnly");
}
```

**Another Note:** For some reason if the session is cleared and the `onsessionstart()` handler is requested this set cookie stuff above will fail. There has to be a try catch block or exception handling of some sort added to account for a reload problem. The best thing is to upgrade to a patched up release of Coldfusion 10 (or soon to be released CF 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PageContext object to set cookies in cfscript:

```
getPageContext().getResponse().addHeader("Set-Cookie", "CFID=#session.CFID#;path=/;HTTPOnly");
getPageContext().getResponse().addHeader("Set-Cookie", "CFTOKEN=#session.CFTOKEN#;path=/;HTTPOnly");
```

Comment: Now this looks do-able. I won't be able to test until Monday.

Comment: I updated the functional code with your example.  There was a change that had to happen.

Comment: OK. I do have the path and other values set in my production code, but for simplicity in the example I left it out and it worked OK for me.

Comment: No problem Jeremy.  Thanks for providing this solution!

Answer (score 1):

For session cookies, there's an easier way.

> **Enabling server-wide HttpOnly session cookies**
>
> The ColdFusion 9.0.1 update added a server-wide setting to add the
>   httponly attribute to all session cookies created by ColdFusion (such
>   as the CFID and CFTOKEN cookies, or the JSESSIONID cookie on JRun). To
>   enable this setting, if you are running a JRun J2EE installation or
>   multi-server installation, you must edit jvm.config, otherwise you can
>   enable this setting from the CF Administrator. If you are running a
>   J2EE server other than JRun consult your documentation for an
>   appropriate setting. J2EE servers that support the Servlet 3.0
>   specification can specify
>   true
>   in the /WEB-INF/web.xml file.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion-securing-apps.html

Comment: Thank you Henry. I didn't know I could handle this in Coldfusion Administrator.  We have someone else admin our servers so on future installs I will make it a requirement, change it on the ones I can access and make it a Application.cfc entry as a catch on the ones I can't access.

Comment: Henry, I updated the answer with what I am using...Take a look. Let me know if you see anything concerning about it.

Comment: @Frank you should turn `sessionmanagement` on, and `setclientcookie` off, and set the `session.cfid` and `session.cftoken` to the cookie yourself, WITHOUT generating any of your own with `createUUID()` call.

Comment: I have both sessionmanagement and setclientcookie set like that already. For my UUID on cftoken I will flip the admin setting and do what you said here and pull that if statement with explicit settings. Thanks again Henry.

Comment: @FrankTudor great, so if it works, I think you should mark Jeremy's answer as the correct answer

Comment: Yea...about that...It doesn't work.  I am running into something with onSessionStart() session.cfid not existing and I can't fully explain it. I am doing testing now to see if I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your application.cfc inside of the onsessionstart function.

```
          <cfcookie name="CFID" value="#session.cfid#" httponly="true">
          <cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="#session.cftoken#" httponly="true">
```

There is no way of setting this inside of cfscripts. cfcookie is not supported in script form in cf9. There are flags in the application settings added to CF10 to address this issue, however, CF11 will have full support for it inside of scripts. Unfortunately, I think you will have to forego the uniform code for functionality. Unless you have access to your CFIDE/Administrator. You can add a java argument to turn it on server wide. Add this to your JVM config

```
-Dcoldfusion.sessioncookie.httponly=true
```

All of this is detailed here http://www.petefreitag.com/item/764.cfm